# Command block check if entity is hovering over another entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can I do a command to check if a dropped item is hovering over a villager named miner and then `tp` that item to a position?

Comment: @CloseVoter - Whilst the question does not show any research effort, How is it 'unclear' what he is asking? [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote, please don't use it as one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/28182)

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objective add Marker dummy
```

Clock (20tps):

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] Marker 0
/execute @e[type=Villager,name=miner] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,r=1] Marker 1
/tp @e[type=Item,score_Marker_min=1] <X> <Y> <Z>
```